# Does Coil 3 have native iOS support?

Tags: ios, kotlin-multiplatform, coil

Does anyone have an example of how to use Coil3 for image loading in a native iOS in a KMM project? I have managed to set it up for android, using a common `ImageLoader`, but i can't figure out how to set it up for iOS. FYI this is not a Compose Multiplatform project, just shared Kotlin logic and native UI per platform

Googled examples, everything seems to point to compose multiplatform, but I need native implementation, if it exists.

Comment: Coil 3 is adding support of Compose Multiplatform, [documentation](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/upgrading_to_coil3/) says nothing about native support. I'm not even sure what you expected from it - if you're only sharing logic with kotlin, how are you going to use picture library to share logic?